# React app crashes when re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have multiple routes in my react, redux application and when navigating to a new route everything works fine, but when I refresh the page it crashes, because it tries you use data that haven't been fetched yet:
This is inside of my reducer)

```
export const getDoorById = (reduxStore, door) => {
  console.log(reduxStore.fetchDoors.doors) // Nothing here
  return reduxStore.fetchDoors.doors.find(item => item._id == door)
}
```

So I tried to make a "LoadingWrapper" around all of my components:

```
export default class LoadingWrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.isLoading) {
      return <CircularProgress />
    } else {
      return this.props.children
    }
  }
}
```

And it works fine on components who actually dispatches isLoading = true, like here:

```
export function fetchEvents(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // CUSTOMERS
    case 'FETCH_CUSTOMERS':
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }
```

But on some of the other components reducers (they are exact same) it doesnt work and no loading icon shows up. So everything gets messed up.

I just wonder how I can fix this annoying bug that makes me unable to refresh the page.

#### Edit:

Here's my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false
}

export function fetchDoors(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_DOORS':
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }

    case 'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, doors: action.payload.setDoors, isLoading: false }

    case 'FETCH_CONTROLLERS':
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }

    case 'FETCH_CONTROLLERS_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        controllers: action.payload.setControllers,
        isLoading: false
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

// This tries to get the array of 'doors'
export const getDoorById = (reduxStore, door) => {
  return reduxStore.fetchDoors.doors.find(item => item._id == door)
}

export const getControllerById = (reduxStore, controllerId) => {
  return reduxStore.fetchDoors.controllers.find(
    item => item._id == controllerId
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you pass isLoading property true when dispatching an action and is it correctly reflected in the state by the reducer? If some of your actions do not set isLoading true then maybe you can have additional check of "this.props.isLoading == null" in your condition and show loading dialog even if isLoading prop is empty

Comment: In my initial state for my reducer I set `isLoading` to false and then I have a case when I set it to `true` and when it has finished fetching I set it to `false`.

Comment: @codeslayer1 I added my reducer that fails. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Can you also tell the error when it crashes?

Comment: @codeslayer1yes, the error says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` here: `return reduxStore.fetchDoors.doors.find(item => item._id == door)`

Comment: In that case, the error is occurring because your fetchDoors object does not have a property called doors and so it is undefined. Please log your fetchDoors object and check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154533/discussion-between-martin-nordstrom-and-codeslayer1).

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
  if(!this.props.children && !isLoading) return null;

 if (this.props.isLoading) {
   return <CircularProgress />
 } else {
   return this.props.children
 }
}
```